# Mixed model for three factors (split split plot design) with proportions as response

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, lme4-nlme, split-plot

I am struggling with the analysis of a data set from an experiment done as follows:

I have 5 blocks (that work as replicates) and each one of them was divided into two part (so split block), to each part a fertilization treatment was assigned (so fertilization treatment has two levels F and U). Each fertilization treatment was divided two times (so split split block) to assign a pollination treatment (so pollination has two levels called A and B). Finally each pollination treatment was divided 15 times to allocate 15 different species.

I am trying to find out whether the treatments have an effect on the proportion of fruits produced by each species (the proportion is calculated as the number of viable fruits in the plant/total number of fruits produced by the plant)
My **response variable** is the **proportion of fruits** on each plant and my **explanatory variables** are **fertilization, pollination and species**.

So far I understand two things: First, I have to use a binomial distribution since my response variable is a proportion and secondly, I have to specify a nested structure for my model since species is nested in pollination, pollination is nested in fertilization and fertilization is nested in block.

I defined the model in `R` like:

```
m8 <- lmer(fruitprop ~ ffer * fpol * fspe, random=~1|fblock/ffer/fpol/fspe, family=binomial).
```

I am not sure I am doing things right, I have found similar examples in books and googling that are similar to my experimental design, but the outcome that R provides them is different to mine (eg. I don´t get residuals in the outcome).

I plot the residuals vs fitted values from this model and I clearly got a pattern:
[image]

so does it mean the model is not properly set?

Comment: Not sure how you got your model to work... The code seems to mix `lme()` and `lmer()` syntax. Which package were you using? You probably want `glmer()` from the `lme4` package?

Comment: Also was "each fertilization treatment divided two times" or split in half? If you divide it two times, you should get 3 levels for it, no?

Comment: Thanks for your reply stefan, about the model. I used lme(). About the fertilization treatment, it was divided in half, not two times. I'll correct that now. Thanks